# regex for 4 letter word of particular occurance

Tags: php, regex

I am interested in regex for finding the following pattern.

I or E for the 1st letter, N or S 2nd, F or T 3rd, and J or P 4th.

This would identify ISTJ, ESTP,ENTP but not EJPT.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Should be simple, using [Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): `[IE][NS][FT][JP]`

For a whole word: `\b[IE][NS][FT][JP]\b`
For the whole input: `^[IE][NS][FT][JP]$`

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/6VCwduNiTX

Example PHP code: http://ideone.com/XgbFWY

```
$ptn = "/[IE][NS][FT][JP]/"; // use "/[IE][NS][FT][JP]/i" to ignore case
$str = "ISTJ, ESTP,ENTP but not EJPT";
preg_match_all($ptn, $str, $matches);
```